# How to send emails from Rails 4 with Postfix on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I know this question is posted already here but all the solutions provided didn't work for me.
I already installed Postfix and tested it successfully with:

```
date | mail -s test myemail@example.com
```

My config/environments/production.rb has:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "localhost",
  :port => 25,
  :domain => "myhost",
}

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

I even changed :smtp with :sendmail

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

It didn't work as well.
The /var/log/mail.log doesn't show anything my application log as well nothing.
Postfix is up and running fine, any help is much appreciated.

Ps: Is there something I am missing here? I only want to send emails from my app not receive them.

Comment: Is postfix listening on port 25? netstat -an  will show you.

Comment: Yes tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: And you restarted your server after the changes. There should be some log entries even if they failed.

Comment: I've just restarted it still nothing, the log only shows the restarting process nothing more.